# Are dispatch events not necessary in Flex/ AS 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am creating a application, in which i am calling many functions, But some say, its not the right way to right the functions, you need to dispatch the events for better results. Please can anyone clear me regarding the benefits of dispatch events, as it many websites only says that "it executes an event".

The question may feel foolish, but the answer will let help me in learning flex in right way.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Using events instead of callbacks? This is a complicated matter to properly determine to whether one should use events, callbacks or a mix of both.

Comment: it is down to synchonous and asynchronouse execution of your code. with functions approach it is synchronouse - each call to function waits for previous call to finish - thus hanging, with events you can call function which may dispatch an event and you will in response to taht event call another function - thus it's not hanging code execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you find yourself writing code that has `parent.somefunction()` or `outerdocument.someotherfunction()`, that is the time to use events.  Code like that makes the child component dependent on it's parent.  The better way to have a function executed on the parent would be to use `addEventListener()` on the parent class to register a listener function and then to call `dispatchEvent()` in the child.

If you get into writing itemRenderers for datagrids or list components, you will need to learn this technique.

Comment: Thanks for the response..., Now its clear that, If I want my code not to hang at any point I should use events for easy flow of code. In mine application there is a table(datagrid) to whom I written a `outerdocument.callfun()`, so now I will change that and will try to use events. Thanks for you knowledge sharing with me. Thanks again